# I want to update my Micromax A87 Android 2.3 Gingerbread to Android 4. ICS

Tags: updates, micromax-a87

Please tell me step by step how can i install Android 4 ICS to my Android 2.3 Gingerbread, I am new to Android but i can do this, if some one help.

Comment: Currently no ICS rom available for your phone.  
First step in Installing new rom is Rooting.

Answer (score 2):

I am afraid, it might not be possible.

First of all, the ideal requirement for ICS to run on any phone is Dual Core processor, and your phone does not have good processor.

Secondly the ram, your phone has only 256MB of RAM wherein for ICS to work smoothly, it requires atleast 512MB RAM.

Comment: Dual core processor is not a criteria to run ICS.
Galaxy s plus,galaxy s, galaxy s duos etc are already running ICS. There are also so many phones which are already running ICS in them.

Comment: but the phone would be slow and laggy if the processor is not dual core atleast. also the ram plays an important part.

Comment: I have a HTC One V, its a single core Snapdragon, with 512 MB RAM running AOKP. It all depends upon the ROM/Stock OS running on the device and services running  in the background. I run 4.1.2 smoothly.